# Android Samsung: how to intent samsung file explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, file-manager

I would like to get a nicer file explorer as the one which is chosen automatically by Intent. On my phone there is also the file explorer from Samsung. However it never shows up.

Here my code snippet in Kotlin

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                data = selectedUri
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            }
```

Comment: There are hundreds upon hundreds of devices from Samsung. Not all will ship with a file explorer app. Not all will ship with the *same* file explorer app or ones that necessarily support the same `Intent` structures. But you can use apps like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo) to examine the manifest of installed apps and see what `<intent-filter>` options they offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*"); 
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

For Samsung Users

```
val intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

For more refernce check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html